# Adding nested columns to jstl report by datatables dandelion

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, datatables, jstl, dandelion

I am using dandelion in order to show a table (from an hibernate DB):

```
<datatables:table id="listPersons" data="${listPersons}" row="person" 
                  cellspacing="0" width="100%"
                  theme="bootstrap2" pageable="true" info="true">
        <datatables:column title="Person" property="person"/>
        <datatables:column title="Car" property="car"/>
</datatables:table>
```

it works fine.

But, I need to add additional two columns from a Parents class (hibernate DB): "Father name" and Mother name".
The class (which also hibernate) have the variable: `Parents parents;`

I tried something like:

```
<c:forEach items="${person.parents}" var="parents"> 
    <datatables:column title="Father name" property="parents.father_name"/>
</c:forEach>
```

But I got the exception:

> javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Unknown property 'father_name' on class 'class org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag'

I tried doing it in many variations (using dandelion datatables) but no one works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change to

```
<datatables:column title="Father name">
    <c:forEach items="${person.parents}" var="parent">
        <c:out value="${parent.father_name}"/>
    </c:forEach>
</datatables:column>
```

The problem you're having is that `property="parents.father_name"/>` is not using the variable you've set in *forEach*, rather uses the parents property from the hibernate entity which is a collection